# mod_rewrite in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Our web server is structured as follows

```
/path-to-docdir     [Contains main pages]
        ./app/      [Some application not directly related to the main content]
```

The main pages are served fine. In the app directory I am trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect all pages to an `index.php` in a public directory

So a request to

```
/server/app/start/login/ => /server/app/public/index.php 
/server/app/start/login  => /server/app/public/index.php
/server/app/start/login?name=someone => /server/app/public/index.php?name=someone
```

The front controller relies on the last two components of the `REQUEST_URI` string to interpret controller and action.

To do the above I have created the following `.htaccess` file in the `app` directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$     public/   [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here, I find that the server goes in a redirect loop for the above URLs.  I tried replacing `$1` with `index.php` and that does bring up the page, but the internal references within the page to script files run into errors.

After some searching around, I added the following line:

```
RewriteBase /app/
```

And that did not seem to make any difference. I should also note that everything works as expected if I make the app directory as the server root directory.

I've also turned on debug logging and all I could gather from that was that the server was indeed going into a redirect loop.

```
[perdir /path-to-docdir/app/] internal redirect with /app/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/public/start/login/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

I'm not really sure where to start looking at this point, so any help or pointers to move me further would be much appreciated.

Edit:

This htaccess file worked for me - if anyone else is looking for a solution. Apparently, I was missing rewrite conditions

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points:

A `RewriteBase` path does not need a trailing slash, so `RewriteBase /app/` should be `RewriteBase /app`.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1` makes `RewriteRule ^$ public/` superfluous.  The former will match `http://yourserver/app` and internally rewrite as `http://yourserver/app/public`, so there's no need for the latter.

Finally, try adding a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Yes, I did need a rewrite condition. And yes, you are right the first rule was superfluous. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Although the solution did not work in it's entirety. I did find it useful, but I'm sorry I don't have enough points to upvote.

Comment: No problem.  If you want your own answer to be the "accepted" one, you can post it as an answer yourself, instead of an edit to the question, and then mark it as accepted.